# Umbraco on Azure

Tags: azure, umbraco

We deployed umbraco DB and umbraco site on azure. The top level umbraco admin page works (abc.xyz.com/umbraco/login.aspx), however, we have multiple domains created (lmn.abc.xyz.com, pqr.abc.xyz.com and so on). We cannot see other websites coming up. The page just displays that these sites are available (abc.xyz.com). Your help is much appreciated in this regards.

Thank you.

Pravin

Comment: Silly one, but have you created the CNAME-s pointing to the [your_service].cloudapp.net ?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am just asking another obvious question. Have you add host name information to Umbraco nodes? I am assuming multiple sites under Content node in Umbraco. Right click on the node and select "Manage hostnames", add host names to each node.

```
lmn-Home
  Page 1
  Page 2
abc-Home
  Page 1
  Page 2
```

Browse the pages locally (URL in properties tab). i.e. localhost:port/lmn-home/page1 etc.